# How to display BitmapImage correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, listbox

I'd like to display some images from a SQL Server database in a ListBox. I convert the image from binary to `BitmapImage` and wenn I add like this:

```
foreach (var screenshot in screenshots)
{
    ImageListBox.Items.Add(screenshot);
}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Output]

How can I show the image(s) correctly?

EDIT: This is my xaml code:

```
<ListBox Name="ImageListBox">
</ListBox>
```

EDIT 2:

This is how I convert the images:

```
public BitmapImage ConvertImage(byte[] value)
{
    if (value != null && value.Length > 0)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(value))
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.StreamSource = stream;
            image.EndInit();
            return image;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And this is my query:

```
var screenshots = context
    .Error.Include(_ => _.ErrorScreenshots)
    .First(_ => _.Id == selectedError.Id)
    .Error
    .Select(_ => new { Image = ConvertImage(_.Screenshot) })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Read about [data templates](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) (see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)).

Comment: Have I understood that correct: ListBox calls toString() by default and that's why it looks weird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListBox will default to displaying an object using its toString() method. In your case you end up with "Image = System.Windows.Media.Bitmap.Image"

In order to indicate that each item should be displayed as an Image object, specify an ItemTemplate.

```
<ListBox Name="ImageListBox">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Image Source="{Binding}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I've got some problems with the source. The image comes from the database and I have no idea what source I should specify.

Comment: I updated the answer. I think in your case, since you are using a BitmapImage object you can just bind directly to the object, instead of binding to ImageSource. A BitmapImage is an ImageSource so that should work.

Comment: Is it possible, that the image is empty/null? [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xj371j2qc6jwyon/ImageIsNull.png?dl=0)

Comment: @J.Doe You're certainly doing something wrong when you create the BitmapImages. You should post that code too.

Comment: Maybe, if your conversion didn't work. I tested the solution, adding two different BitmapImage objects to ListBox.Items. One Bitmapimage I created from a local file, the other I created from binary data. Both showed up just fine in the ListBox.